# Как создать процесс для каждой обработки каждой строки массива в linux?

Tags: linux, c, процесс

Запуталась с процессами. Необходимо выполнить обработку каждой строки(поиск простых чисел и их среднее арифметическое) в отдельном процессе. Не понимаю, куда именно нужно вставлять fork(). Разбирающиеся люди, объясните,пожалуйста.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main()
{   const int M=5;
    const int N=100;
    int arr[5][100];
        int i, j, sum, qty;
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < M; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < N; j++ )
        arr[i][j] = rand()%100+1;
    }
        //    view
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < M; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < N; j++ )
        printf("%d\t",arr[i][j]);
        printf ("\n");

    }

    for (int i = 0 ; i < 10; ++ i){
        pid_t PID = fork();
        if (PID == -1)
        {
            printf("Error!\n");
            return(0);
        } 
        else if (PID == 0){
        printf(" CHILD: Дочерний процесс. \n");
        printf(" CHILD: Мой PID — %d \n", getpid());
        printf(" CHILD: PID моего родителя — %d \n", getppid());
            const size_t M = 5;
            const size_t N = 100;
            //setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
            srand(time(NULL));

        int is_prime(double n)
        {
             int i;
             if (n <= 1) return false;

             for (i=2; i<=sqrt(n); i++)
                 {
                     if (((int)n % i) == 0) return false;
                 }
                 return true;


        }


    for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        sum = qty = 0;  
        for (j = 0; j < 100; ++j)
            if (is_prime(arr[i][j])) {
                sum += arr[i][j];
                ++qty;
            }
        printf("Среднее арифметическое в строке %d равно %d\n", i, (int)sum / qty);
    }
exit(0);
    }
    else{
        printf(" PARENT: Это процес-родитель. \n");
        printf(" PARENT: Мой PID — %d \n", getppid());
        printf(" PARENT: PID моего потомка — %d \n", PID);
    }
}
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вашу задачу сильно облегчает тот факт, что ваши дочерние процессы НИКАК не взаимодействуют между собой. Это означает, что:

1. При запуске каждого процесса он получает копию всех исходных данных
2. Результат своей работы он просто печатает и возвращать его родители не нужно.

Сколько у Вас строк? N==100? Ну так и запускайте 100 процессов! Совершенно непонятно, зачем у Вас этот цикл:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < 10; ++ i){
        pid_t PID = fork();
```

Это к чему ?! Есть только одна проблема - как сказать процессу, какую строчку он обрабатывает? Можно просто взять параметр цикла, который запускает 100 процессов. Эскиз программы выглядит так:

```
void find_prime(int *arr) {
 . . .
};

void calculate_average(int *arr) {
 . . .
};

pid_t pid;

for (int line_num=0; line_num<100; line_num++) {
    pid = fork();
    if(pid < 0) {
        // Обработка ошибок
        exit(); // Завершаем всю программу
    } else if (pid > 0) {
        // В главном процессе - продолжаем цикл
        continue;
    } else {
        // В дочеренем процессе - обрабатываем строку
        find_prime(arr[line_num]); // Ищем все простые числа
        calculate_average(arr[line_num]); // И среднее значение
    }
}
```